# How to fix this error call google location to address Service "target machine actively refused it"

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-services, google-api

When trying to call Google location to address Service, it gives me this message:

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it 173.194.66.95:80

I use ASP.net 4 with C#.
This is my code:

```
protected void btn_FindAddress_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=";
    query = LatY.Text + "," + LongX.Text + "&sensor=true";

    Address.Text = url;
    Uri uri = new Uri (url + query);

    // Create a request for the URL. 
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
    //// If required by the server, set the credentials.
    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    // Get the response.
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    // Display the status.
    Status.Text = (((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
    // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
    Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
    // Read the content.
    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
    // Display the content.
    Address.Text = responseFromServer;
    // Clean up the streams and the response.
    reader.Close();
    response.Close(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Most commonly, the outbound connection can be established (the remote server could be reached *and* a response was sent in a timely fashion) but the port you're trying to use is being blocked (a firewall or a proxy are the two most likely options I can think of).

It also *might* derive from the fact that there is no server on the other side of the connection: this may happen for example if you NAT port 80 to a system which doesn't have a web server. Being that you're invoking Google's url, I doubt it's the case, but I thought it worth of pointing out.